# Wrapper around ng-repeat list item after every 10 item

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a scenario in which I have to create a new ul if inner li list item reach every 10th option.
For example here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knzaxh76/). I have two variables and each variable contains a number of options. I have outer ng-repeat on row div and inner repeat on list item li. Due to some design issues I have to create a new ul if inner li options reach 10 count. That is a ul can handle only 10 item list. How can I do this dynamically without affecting existing variable code. I tries some group by stuff but it is limited to modify your existing variable array.

Here is the code

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="grid-list">
    <div class="grid-row" ng-repeat="variable in variables track by $index">
      <div class="grid_question"> {{variable.name}}
        <ul class="grid-list"> /// add new ul after every 10 option, ul can contain only 10 list.
          <li ng-repeat="option in variable.options track by $index">{{option.name}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS Code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.variables = [{
      name: 'List 1',
      options: [{
        name: 'Option 1',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 2',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 3',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 4',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 5',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 6',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 7',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 8',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 9',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 10',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 11',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 12',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 13',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'List 2',
      options: [{
        name: 'Option 1',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 2',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 3',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 4',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 5',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 6',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 7',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 8',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 9',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 10',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 11',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 12',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }, {
        name: 'Option 13',
        value: '',
        has_comment: false
      }]
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: slicing the options arrays into sub arrays and adding `ng-repeat` on `<ul>` would be simplest approach

Comment: Can you provide an example without changing existing arrays

Comment: What's wrong with slicing the existing arrays?

Comment: Will existing option array be changed using slicing?

Comment: That would be simplest...yes

Comment: I am thinking to about limitTo filter with start and limit option